# Worst case scenario Quicksort binary tree

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I was taking a closer look at the worst case scenario for Quicksort algorithm. I found that the binary tree looks something like this.

[image]

Does somebody understand where the 2 comes from?

Thanks

Comment: Each partial sum is for the number of nodes at that level. So the second line is the sum of the left node of 1 + right node of n-1 = n. The next to last line doesn't show the left node of 1 next to the 2, but that is why the partial sum is 3. The last line shows the left and right node, each with a count of 1 which is why the partial sum is 2.

Comment: It's the sum of the two bottom leaves?

Comment: @Carlos - yes. Each partial sum is a sum of the counts shown to the left and on the same line a the partial sum. What's confusing is the left child with count of 1 that should be on the same line with the 2 and 3 is not shown in the diagram.

Comment: Hello @rcgldr, thanks for your answer. I understand that the right side is the partial sum. But I meant the 2 from the left side. Why is their a two? Shouldn´t the base case be T(1)=1 for Quicksort? It should go from "n-c" until it hit's the base case which mentioned above is T(1)=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 comes from adding 1 + 1. and each 1 comes from O(n) of 1 element. 
In quicksort, after finding the pivot and then sorting the array with respect to the pivot takes O(n) time. 
Your smallest arrays are each of size 1, in the end are each of size 1.